# How can I iterate a dictionary which is into another dictionary to get specific values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate a dictionary that is into another dictionary to get 2 values (content and completed_date) of each set but I don't know how to do it. This is the data:

```
{  
   'items':[  
      {  
         'content':'Get a solution for the server @connect',
         'meta_data':None,
         'user_id':20440353,
         'task_id':3186948449,
         'project_id':2203217746,
         'completed_date':'Tue 07 May 2019 18:31:47 +0000',
         'id':3186948449
      },
      {  
         'content':'Fix the Placement test based on the feedback @connect',
         'meta_data':None,
         'user_id':20440353,
         'task_id':3186363895,
         'project_id':2203217746,
         'completed_date':'Tue 07 May 2019 14:52:27 +0000',
         'id':3186363895
      }
   ],
   'projects':{  

   }
}
```

This is what I've been trying:

```
>>> for items in itstuff_data['items']:
...     print(items)
...
```

But is giving me everything inside of 'items' (as expected). Is there a way to iterate the data to get just content and completed_date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: `print( items['content'], items['completed_date'] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way, you just need to loop again!

```
itstuff = {  
   'items':[  
      {  
         'content':'Get a solution for the server @connect',
         'meta_data':None,
         'user_id':20440353,
         'task_id':3186948449,
         'project_id':2203217746,
         'completed_date':'Tue 07 May 2019 18:31:47 +0000',
         'id':3186948449
      },
      {  
         'content':'Fix the Placement test based on the feedback @connect',
         'meta_data':None,
         'user_id':20440353,
         'task_id':3186363895,
         'project_id':2203217746,
         'completed_date':'Tue 07 May 2019 14:52:27 +0000',
         'id':3186363895
      }
   ],
   'projects':{  

   }
}



for obj in itstuff["items"]:
    for key in obj:
        if (key == "content" or key == "completed_date"):
            # Do something with values
            print(obj[key])
```

Comment: This is giving me the result that I needed in an appropriate format and also the logic makes sense for me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, `items` will probably always be a dictionary; to now access the `"content"` and the `"completed_date"`, you can just index into that dictionary:

```
items["content"]
items["completed_date"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

# foo(d) == (d['content'], d['completed_date'])
foo = itemgetter("content", "completed_date")

for content, completed_date in map(foo, itstuff_data['items']):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=[]
for dic in itstuff_data['items']:
         data.append((dic['content'],dic['completed_date']))
         print(dic['content'],dic['completed_date'])
```

you can also iterate through a dictionary object as

`for k,v in dic.items()` or `for item in dic: print(dic[item])`

Comment: itstuff_data["items"] should be a list with dictionary, therefore items will always be a dictionary already, in which you can index. Your second loop is not needed or rather wrong in this context.